# xlabel of DataFrame.plot appears on the y-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm creating a stacked bar plot via the code below:

```
ax = df.plot(
    kind="barh",
    stacked=True,
    width=0.9,
    figsize=(10, 11),
    colormap="RdYlGn",
    xlabel='% Respondents'
);
```

But the label for the x-axis appears on the y-axis! If I change `xlabel` to `ylabel`, the text on the y-axis does not move.

How can I get a label on the x-axis?

Comment: Hmm. Unable to repro. What version of pandas? Sample data might also be helpful.

Comment: Pandas version 1.1.5

Comment: Upgraded pandas version to 1.5.3 and now the label is in the right place! Must be a weird bug with the previous version. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a bug with pandas version 1.1.5. Upgrading to pandas version 1.5.3 resolved the issue.